# JQuery - proper and efficient usage of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I have started project in JQuery. I am using a lot of "click" and "onchange" events in my project. Initially it was ok ( when there were not more lines of code ) but after 500-600 lines of code my source code is getting VERY messy because I have a lots of click and onchange events everywhere in my code. I don't know how to handle this problem, how can I use click and onchange events properly, efficient and not messy? Is there any framework or special pattern for this kind of projects? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give me some sample of your code with click and change event?

Comment: Q. What is the correct number of click and onchange events on a page? A. However many it takes to achieve the desired functionality. If your existing code works and you just want some tips to tidy it up (a) you'd have to show us the code, but (b) this is probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I am using click events more, when I have to to some action when user clicks to button or link. Example, edit table columns, save changes, change select options and display up to selected menu and so on..

Comment: 30-35 click events in one page

Comment: Some part of my code is working but it's very messy and I got some errors and because of messy code I couldn't find it. That's why I want to rewrite the whole page with some pattern or framework I don't know what ever is tidy code

Comment: look for repeated patterns and consolidate code accordingly. Very common refactoring process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attaching a lot of event handlers, first of all, you should make your code understandable and readable. Follow the *DRY principle*. You don't need to repeat jQuery-selectors attaching events to the one:

```
$(".divname").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        // Handle mouseenter...
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        // Handle mouseleave...
    },
    click: function() {
        // Handle click...
    }
}, "a");
```

Next, be bother about any functionality duplication. For example, when several buttons/links perform the same or closely the same action, this action/function should be declared **non-anonymousely** to be reusable:

```
function editTableColumn() { ... }
$("#element1, #element2").on("click", editTableColumn);
```

or with distinction param:

```
function editTableColumn(param1) { if (param1 == ) ... }
  $("#element1").on("click", function() {
  var param1 = "one";
  editTableColumn(param1);
});
$("#element2").on("click", function() {
  var param1 = "two";
  editTableColumn(param1);
});
```

the same idea in jQuery may be accomplished with a custom **plugin**: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

If DOM manipulations are seriously mixed with js-structure, you simply need a kind of pseudoclass or a contructor function...

Actually my advice would be to use **JS framework** ment for a lot of interactivity: EmberJS, AngularJS, etc. Using the last, for example, you'll accomplish your tasks (displaying/hiding/sorting data and doing other DOM manipulations) even without jQuery within less, much less code.
Here you could find few examples of Angular default orderBy filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Just pickup a few examples from the web when deciding.